# Entity Framework inheritance creating coresponding entity

Tags: entity-framework-4

I have an EF model where I logically have a "template" type and an "instance of the template type"

Basically my templates are like a work flow and the instances are those templates applied to an object. The association is that a template has zero to many instances, an instance is always based on a template. For example the template may be “send letter”   which gets applied to a customer to create an instance of the letter sent, which includes the date sent, the pdf of the letter etc.

The templates have a few subclasses/types which will always match an instance which also has a corresponding subclass.

The issue is how can I ensure that when I create an instance (which will have a reference to the template) that the instance is of the correct inherited type.

For example if the template is of type TemplateType2 (inherits from template)  and I add an instance to loan1 .. loan1.TemplateInstances.add(foo) … I want to ensure that foo is of type InstanceType2.

The way I am doing it now seems like such a hack.  I am storing the instance entity name as a scalar value in the template entity, and using reflection to create the correct type of the instance.

It works, but it is basically using the value of a property to do mapping, exposing the possibility of all sorts of errors if they do not match the name of the instance name, or worse if they enter the wrong entity name.

Any ideas or thoughts how to tackle this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving this through a bit of a hack.
I used naming conventions and adding my own handler to the context savingchanges method
and then a bit of reflection.  Not the best solution but it works.

the main part...

```
   For Each entry As ObjectStateEntry In DirectCast(sender, ObjectContext).ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Added)
            If Not entry.IsRelationship Then

[blah blah...snip]    

ObjectName = Me.GetType.ToString
                    If ObjectName = "QSEntityFrameWork.TaskTemplate" Then
                        ObjectName = "QSEntityFrameWork.TaskInstance"
                    Else
                        ObjectName = ObjectName.Replace("Task", "Instance")
                    End If
                    oh = Activator.CreateInstance("QSEntityFrameWork", ObjectName)
                    Dim obj As Object = oh.Unwrap
                    obj.TaskTemplateID = Me.TaskTemplateID
                    obj.TaskStartDate = DateTime.Now
                    obj.ProcessInstanceID = ProcessIntanceID
                    Return obj
```